# setExtractView в InputMethodService или как изменить поле ввода при полноэкранном отображении своей клавиатуры?

Tags: android

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как можно изменить layout для ввода текста при полноэкранном отображении своей клавиатуры?

Нашел вот такой вопрос: [линк](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026631/android-inputmethodservice-how-to-set-a-view-with-setextractviewview-view)

Но я не понимаю, как можно применить ответ на этот вопрос?

Напишу более подробно.
Я пишу свою клавиатуру для андроида. В landscape-режиме, когда клавиатура занимает много пространства экрана, вызывается спец лейаут (с большим полем ввода и кнопкой "Done") - вот ее я и хочу поменять на свою. Есть класс InputMethodService, в котором как-раз это всё и описывается, есть метод setExtractView, который и вызывает этот встроенный лейаут. Как поменять встроенный на свой? Что конкретно нужно прописать в этом методе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос.

Чтобы изменить стандартный лейаут, который появляется в полноэкранном режиме клавиатуры, следует переопределить метод **onCreateExtractTextView** в своем классе кастомной клавиатуры (который расширяет основной класс **InputMethodService** естественно)

```
@Override
public View onCreateExtractTextView() {
// edit standard layout for full-sreen mode 
// androidsdk/platforms/android-26/data/res/layout/input_method_extract_view.xml

View inflater = super.onCreateExtractTextView(); // returns standard com.android.internal.R.layout.input_method_extract_view

// extract IDs from input_method_extract_view.xml
Resources res = Resources.getSystem(); // system resources
int id_inputExtractEditText = res.getIdentifier("inputExtractEditText", "id", "android"); // ExtractEditText
int id_inputExtractAccessories = res.getIdentifier("inputExtractAccessories", "id", "android"); // FrameLayout
int id_inputExtractAction = res.getIdentifier("inputExtractAction", "id", "android"); // ExtractButton

ExtractEditText inputExtractEditText = inflater.findViewById(id_inputExtractEditText);
FrameLayout inputExtractAccessories = inflater.findViewById(id_inputExtractAccessories);
Button inputExtractAction = inflater.findViewById(id_inputExtractAction);

// do anything with extracted views:
inputExtractEditText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.keyboard_backgound1));
inputExtractAccessories.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.keyboard_backgound2));
inputExtractAction.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.key_GradientGreen));

return inflater;
}
```

Если кто-нибудь знает способ лучше, напишите, пожалуйста.